# Delegation not working on some computers

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, delegation

I have an asp.net application that uses delegation to perform actions on the Active Directory as the authenticating user. The application works perfectly on some computers and doesn't work at all on other computers, on these other computers they receive a `COMexception` error code `0x80072020` the stack trace is:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred.
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FineOne()
at ResetUnlockAccount.ResetUnlockAccount.ExecuteImpersonation(String username)
```

The code that is throwing the error is:

```
WindowsIdentity winId = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;            
WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = null;
try
{
    ctx=winId.Impersonate();
    using (DirectoryEntry directoryObject = new DirectoryEntry(ROOT))
    {
        using (DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(directoryObject))
        {                        
            search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(SAMAccountName=username))";
            search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree; 
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 This line is causing the issue.               
 ---------->SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

            using (DirectoryEntry user = result.GetDirectoryEntry())
            {
                user.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });
                user.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0] = 0;
                user.CommitChanges();
                lblOutput.Text = "It worked";
            }
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblOutput.Text += ex.ToString();
}
finally
{
    if (ctx != null)
        ctx.Undo();
}
```

At first I thought it was a User permission issue, so I tested it by trying my credentials on one of the computers that was having issues, I encountered the same issues. To confirm it wasn't User permission issues I tried it on my workstation with the other persons credentials and it worked perfectly.

I wrote a quick test program that would show me the impersonation level of the users, when working correctly it should be Delegation. When I ran it on my machine the output was:

```
Authentication Type: Negotiate
Token: 9999
Name: domain\username
Is Authenticated: True
Impersonation level: Delegation
```

When I ran it on the other Workstation:

```
Authentication Type: Negotiate
Token: 9999
Name: domain\username
Is Authenticated: True
Impersonation level: Impersonation
```

Server: IIS 7.0
Browser: IE 8

I don't know what is causing the issue with only certain computers, if anyone knows of a specific setting that should be changed for delegation to work properly I would be grateful. Below I have posted two other links that will help give more insight into my problem.

[.GetDirectoryEntry throws COM exception, code:0x800720720 when attempting to bind to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271350/getdirectoryentry-throws-com-exception-code0x800720720-when-attempting-to-bin)

[asp.net application userprincipal.findbyidentity works with browser on server, throws exception from my machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24249586/asp-net-application-userprincipal-findbyidentity-works-with-browser-on-server-t)

Comment: You should add some information. There's none in your question.

Comment: What kind of information? I don't really have any code that is bugging out on me, because it works for some computers and doesn't for others. The most I can give you is that it breaks when binding to a directory entry object and give the `0x80072020' COMexception error, which pretty much just means any security issue with Active Directory

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I can't see how anyone could possibly help you, unless they happened to be able to remember the same thing happening to them. You do not give any information on the what is going on when "delegation fails", how your machines are set up, or anything else that would help to diagnose the problem. And, BTW, paragraphs are good to use.

Comment: You're right John, just give me a few minutes and I'll fill in some blanks for you, provide some code and a call stack trace, and as much information as I can about the setup.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Is that better?

Comment: Much better. I retracted my close vote and +1. Please note the difference between the "before" and "after" and take it into consideration on future questions.

Comment: Will do, Thank you for that, also any idea what might be causing this rather confusing a frustrating behaviour?

Comment: No idea, but I'd be looking in event logs.

Comment: Sounds like a client config issue, bordering on something more suited for ServerFault. But for starters, Open IE, Settings, Advanced, Security, [x] Enable Integrated Auth.

Comment: @HenkHolterman that was the first thing I checked, all machines have Enable Integrated Authentication checked off.

Comment: Weren't you meant to do something with the [WindowsImpersonationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx)?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I was I just missed it when copying the code over somehow, added it in there just inside the Try block

Comment: That is something else to mention in the question, as are Server version, Browser version(s) etc. Check how the computers are configured in the AD. After that: examine Eventlogs (C & S), and then look at Fiddler or similar tool.

Comment: Ok, but I suggest using a `using` block, as in the link I posted.

Comment: I will try that, and see if it makes a difference, but since I need to get a different machine to test it, it may take a while.

Comment: No change in behaviour